# Dynamically adding new property: value to a model from mongoose findOne

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to implement forgotten password recovery logic in my application.

Here is my Express router:

```
router.post('/passwordreset', function(req, res) {
User.findOne({'local.email' : req.body.email}, function(err, user) {
    if(err) throw err;
    if(user) {
      // creating a token for this user's password reset
      let token = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
      // creating a password reset link
      let url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + '/passwordreset/' + token;
      // fetching recivier email
      let email = user.local.email;
      // setting reset token to user and saving it's modified model
      user.add({resetToken: token});
      user.save(function(err) {
        if(err) throw err;
            mailer.passwordReset(email, url);
      });
    }else {
      res.render('login', {message: 'Email is not found in database!'});
    }
});
});
```

I don't have a "resetToken" property in my mongoose User schema, but I want to add it dynamically so I can later on search for a user by this token and assign new password for it. I know that it is possible to delete unused properties by assigning "undifined" to them before saving, but is there a wise versa solution to add properties to the object I get from findOne function?

user.add keep saying that it is not a function. Any suggestions?

PS. I know that I can create an empty "resetToken" property beforehand and use it for storing and overriding token, but i don't know if it's the best and only one solution. Any suggestions? Thanx in advance.

Comment: I already implemented password reset logic in a bit different way. I create reset property object in advance(in mongoose schema) and on user creation it doesn't appear to the db object, because it's undefined. Then following the logic reset token and time stamp is successfully added to db and on new password submit I set undefined again on reset property object and it disappears from db completely again. And so on if i'll create a password reset token again. So that is how I keep my user object as clean as possible inside my database. But the question is still actual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable `strict` option in your users schema.

```
let UsersSchema = new Schema(
    {
        login: String,
        sha256: String,
        group: Number,
        //And so on
    },
    {
        strict: false
    });
```

Link to the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict)

Comment: I'm not gonna use that since I implemented the whole logic a bit differently, but I saw your kind of solution and peeps were saying that it works, so I'll mark your answer as the correct possible one